# UISearchController searchBar in tableHeaderView animating out of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` with a `UITableViewController` as a `searchResultsController`, the `UISearchBar` of this `searchController` is set to be in the `tableHeaderView` of my current `tableView` displayed in my root ViewController. Almost everything is working well, as expected. But in the animation of the `UISearchBar` (When i click on the searchBar and the `UINavigationBar` hides and the searchBar goes to the top, as in the `UISearchDisplayController`) i have a strange behavior. Instead of moving to the position of the `UINavigationBar` (y: 0), it jumps out of the screen and than starts the animation that shows the cancel button. I tried moving my instantiate code to the `viewDidLoad` instead of `init`, and the things are just the same. I think that the center of the problem is in the frame of the `searchResultsController`'s view, but i'm not sure about that(I tried setting the frame, without success). Everything that i am doing is in pure code.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // search controller setup
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.searchController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

And i have a lazy load for the `searchResultsController`:

```
- (UITableViewController *)searchResultsController {
    if (_searchResultsController == nil) {
        _searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;
        _searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    }
    return _searchResultsController;
}
```

I've downloaded the sample code from apple, but they use storyBoards and a xib for UITableViewCell, the SearchController works perfectly in the project. Does anyone had the same problem? How can i fix this? Any solutions or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? Currently having a similar problem with my search bar.

Comment: No, Lorenzo. Unfortunately i used the deprecated api for this issue. With storyboards it seems to work in a good manner(i tried the example app from apple), but in the code i got this weird error.

Comment: Alright thanks anyways.  Could you elaborate on the method you used that worked?  I've been looking at Apple's example as well and they use storyboards for the table and detail view but all of the search bar components are done in code, is this what you did?

Comment: Never mind!  I just noticed I missed the line `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;` which ended up being crucial.

Comment: See if this previous thread is of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326269/uisearchbar-presented-by-uisearchcontroller-in-table-header-view-animates-too-fa/28373171#28373171

Answer (score 23):

Add

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

on `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Working with UITableViewController together with UISearchController, this fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 22):

Have you tried to set the hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation to false?
Solved my headache..

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false;
```

Putting the searchbar in the navigation bar gives a more solid user experience in my opinion (for iphone)

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Comment: Amazing this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot.
Indeed the search bar should be in the navigation bar.

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks!  The obvious question is why?

Comment: Worked for me too!. Thanks. The apple example does not even talk about this option.

Comment: I had a `UIView` as a container for the search bar,  between the nav bar and a table view for results. I had to set `self.definesPresentationContext` to `false` to prevent the container from jumping down by about 44 pixels when the search bar was activated.

Comment: self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false; fixed it for me as well! Thank you!

Comment: Perfect..worked for me..! I added searchbar to navigationItem titleview

Answer (score 17):

To make this clearer @Lorenzo's answer worked for me.

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Comment: Man you are my hero of the day!

Comment: The opposite worked for me! I had a `UIView` as a container for the search bar,  between the nav bar and a table view for results. I had to set `self.definesPresentationContext` to `false` to prevent the container from jumping down by about 44 pixels when the search bar was activated.

Answer (score 7):

Try this out:

First you need to delegate the

> UISearchControllerDelegate

**For Swift**

```
func willPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
}

func willDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift, try:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    edgesForExtendedLayout = []
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the UISearchController works perfectly in one of the my views but not the other.  The problem was with the UITableViewController and not the UIViewController.  If you switch to a UIViewController with a UITableView inside it and properly constrained there are no issues.  I implemented mine with a XIB and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This comment lead me in the right direction to solve my issue.  The constraints described in Option B of this SO answer fixed my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52300159/4704303

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 3.01

```
func willPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController){
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}

func willDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the searchBar was in the tableHeaderView and there was no NavigationBar on screen. But the SearchBar still animated upwards overlapping the status bar when becoming active. The solution to prevent this was to set:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Which is weird because as I said the view controller was not using a navigation bar.