# UISearchController change width when editing starts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm presenting my `tableViewController` in [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal).
In my `viewDidLoad` I've added these few properties to manage tableView:

```
[self setupSearchController];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Whereas **setupSearchController** is

```
-(void)setupSearchController
{
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    //  self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[NSLocalizedString(@"ScopeButtonCountry",@"Country"), NSLocalizedString(@"ScopeButtonCapital",@"Capital")];
   // self.searchController.searchBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
}
```

Now when I run the app it show me searchController as
 
[image]
Which is fine and exactly what I'm looking for. But as soon as it became the first responder this happens:
[image]
By Cancelling it makes it go back to the position it is in the first picture. My question is how to make it stay inside the frame of KGModal. Where as I'm calling it as

```
CPTSearchTableViewController *ivc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CPTSearchTVC"];
    ivc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) - 40, CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) - 80);
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setCloseButtonType:KGModalCloseButtonTypeRight];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentViewController:ivc andAnimated:YES];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setTapOutsideToDismiss:YES];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setModalBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setBackgroundDisplayStyle:KGModalBackgroundDisplayStyleSolid];
```

**UPDATE**

By following one of the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222671/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-in-tableheaderview-animating-out-of-the-screen?rq=1) I've been able to keep it inside the height but not the width of view.
[image]

I just updated the code in VIewDidLoad as

```
 [self setupSearchController];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222671/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-in-tableheaderview-animating-out-of-the-screen?rq=1 you tried these answers?

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney see my updated questions

Comment: can you attach your projct here

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how can I do that?

Comment: attach your project in drop box and give the link

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xgepo3aun9ano5/SampleProject.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the frame and check once

change this line

```
//[[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentViewController:ivc andAnimated:YES];
```

to this

```
  [[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentView:ivc.view andAnimated:YES];
```

for updated answer

```
-(void)showTableView
{
SampleTableViewController *ivc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SampleVC"];
//ivc.delegate = self;
ivc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) - 40, CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) - 80);
[[KGModal sharedInstance] setCloseButtonType:KGModalCloseButtonTypeRight];
 [[KGModal sharedInstance] setTapOutsideToDismiss:NO];
 //[[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentViewController:ivc andAnimated:YES];
 [[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentView:ivc.view andAnimated:YES];
[[KGModal sharedInstance] setTapOutsideToDismiss:YES];
//    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setModalBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[[KGModal sharedInstance] setBackgroundDisplayStyle:KGModalBackgroundDisplayStyleSolid];
}
```

Comment: I added this in `setupSearchController` it didn't work! Yesterday when I changed `self.definesPresentationContext` from`NO` to `YES` the update part of question happened. Meaning the Y remains same but X changes.

Comment: @TalhaCh - ya I also think the same , the problem is when you present the keyboard correct, if you attach the projct I will check and tell to u

Comment: @TalhaCh - ok downloaded over

Comment: @TalhaCh - remove this line `[[searchController searchBar] sizeToFit];` and try once

Comment: removed... still the same! Let me know if you need more classes.

Comment: @TalhaCh - not like that ,if I run that I know excat problem, ok do like create the sample project and try this , if you not get the answer, attach that project I will check

Comment: @TalhaCh - give a some time , i wil run and check

Comment: @TalhaCh - check the updated answer, the error is fixed

Comment: it fixed it :) But now the delegates methods of searchController are not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124986/discussion-between-talha-ch-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @TalhaCh - I understand we need to check

Comment: Hey Anbu! can you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487298/self-view-is-not-calling-the-delegate-methods-of-uisearchcontroller