# How to stick top of the UITableView to the bottom of the UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a UTableView:

```
tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.rowHeight = 60.0
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        tableViewHeightAnchor = tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        let constraints = [tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor), tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor), tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor), tableViewHeightAnchor!]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

and my search bar is:

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a cell"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

but I wish to set my top anchor as:

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchController.searchBar.bottomAnchor)
```

but not as:

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
```

But when I stick it to the bottomAnchor of searchBar the app crashes because of the different hierarchies.

```
'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x6000017a6cc0 "UITableView:0x7f81c4876e00.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x6000017a6dc0 "_UISearchControllerView:0x7f81c2d3fa30.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

How can I solve the problem?
I'm trying to solve this problem already 3 days and no success

Comment: Can you show a sketch of what you are trying to achieve? If you put the search bar into the navigation bar (like in your example) it is correct to pin the table view to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option A (search bar in navigation bar):

```
let tableView = UITableView()
view.addSubview(tableView)

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
navigationItem.searchController = searchController

definesPresentationContext = true

tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
])
```

Option B (search bar as table header view):

```
let tableView = UITableView()
view.addSubview(tableView)

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

definesPresentationContext = true

tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
])
```

[image: Option A]
[image: Option B]

Comment: Thank you! It seems the problem was in NOT using `safeArea`.